# TS 2345 Accessing by key for union two types reports error for not assignable

Tags: typescript

This is for My editor project ...

but I can't figure out why TypeScript semantics thought that `(Type1 & Type2)['key']` is the same as `Type1['key'] & Type2['key']`

```js
type EditorEventMap = {
    contentchange: EditorContentChangeEvent
}
interface EditorContentChangeEvent { /** ...more details */ }

class TypeEvent<EventType = any> {
  call<K extends keyof EventType>(event: K, target?: EventType[K]) {
    return;
  }
}

interface IEditorCoreEvent {
  'change': { e: EditorEventMap['contentchange'] } | null
}

class EditorCore<P = {}, T = {}> extends TypeEvent<IEditorCoreEvent & T> {
  test(e: EditorContentChangeEvent) {
    this.call('change', { e })
  }
}
```

[Click here to see a minimal reproduce on TS_Playground, I cut out some code snippets from my project](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAogJgS2AewE4wG4QHbALICGYUAvFAN4BQUNUAxsrjsHQBYHYDmEAXLIilQBhRsGZD2XCJmaUAvpQRNUAMwJ1o8JGhFNcEjtxm4KUAPQAqC1AB0dgLZpocCMAIIANgGcoFs1AVKOg8CLx8AFXBpLFwAHmNgSMhSKA4QAD4KanoCDw9YgGkoCAAPMWw4HwBrCBBkFVgYxKj0gAoIJr4CgBooN1RuYAB+PgSkiABtAoBdAEos2ihUVwBXVGwAbmyFQKUxVXVoAEktQRFlhIWoAHI2QwhrvnJi0YE0BMIwCdvRZjupa7TAJQAA+UGwKzy8koQRCYX42mETliAAUUuQ5L1wui5JlSuVKlBxglYic3kiLk0oAAyImZKg0MReYDtV6I3TlYAGKQJeYM2jAVgILw2Oi5DytW6SbjXXrPaByWbbeRAA)

Comment: `EditorContentChangeEvent` is not assignable to `EditorEventMap['contentchange'`. Please share full example